# Abstraction with "this" variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a crossword puzzle. Here is one example of one box of the crossword:

```
<div class="grid-item">M
    <input id="input-item24" type = "text" size= "4">
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item-black"></div>
</div>
<button id='total_score'>Click to see score</button>
<div id='display_score'></div>
```

Here is the script for each box:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
<script> 
var answers = [];
    answers[2]= 'M';
    answers[3]= 'E';
    answers[4]='A';
    answers[5]= 'L';
    answers[6]= 'B';
    answers[7]= 'E';
    answers[8]='L';
    answers[9]= 'L';
    answers[10]= 'A';
    answers[11]= 'I';
    answers[12]= 'L';
    answers[13]= 'I';
    answers[14]= 'A';
    answers[15]= 'D';
    answers[16]= 'R';
    answers[17]= 'E';
    answers[18]= 'T';
    answers[19]= 'R';
    answers[20]= 'Y';
    answers[21]= 'D';
    answers[22]= 'E';
    answers[23]= 'E';
    answers[24]= 'M';
    var score = 0;
    var total = 0;
```

I want to abstract (condense it) the calculate function by using the "THIS variable" to calculate the score. This way, I won't have to repeat this code (which works) for every box:

```
$('#total_score').on('click',calculate);
    function calculate(){

    if($('#input-item21').val()==answers[21]){total = total +1;}
    $('#display_score').html(total);
   };
```

So far I have tried this, why won't it work?

```
$('.grid-item').on('click',calculate);

    function calculate (){

      if($(this).html() == '')
      {
        $(this).html(answers);

      if(answers == '#input-item')
        {score = score + 1;};   
      }
      $('#display_score').html(score);}

    };
```

Comment: Your `answers` is array, so you can't simply put it as string. Also `answers == '#input-item'` is always false. Maybe you wish to do `typeof answers[$(this).find('input').val()] !== 'undefined'` to check if current element 's input value is in answers array?

Comment: Thank you! if the input of the user equaled the answer for the box, I wanted the score to increase.

Comment: `$(this).html()` includes the `<input>` that's inside the DIV. Maybe you meant `$(this).text()`? You should also use `.trim()` to remove the surrounding whitespace.

Comment: Also, `$(this).html(answers)` will replace the `<input>` with that. Is that what you want?

Answer (score -2):

You should just need to reference the value and id, like this (i would also make it a `blur` event so that the calculation occurs after the user enters info in the square):

```
$('.grid-item').on('blur',calculate);

function calculate (){
  let input = $(this)[0]

  if(input.value || input.value !== '') {
    let id = /\d+$/.match(input.id)[0];

    if(id && answers[id] === input.value) {
      score++;
    }

    $('#display_score').html(score);
  }
};
```

You can also pass the event target to your calculate function, such as below. I would consider further simplifying things by changing the input ids to just numbers (e.g. `#input_item24` to just `24`) and then using that to check the answers array by passing the click target to the calculate function:

```
$('.grid-item').on('blur', e => { calculate(e.target) });

function calculate (input){
  if(input.value || input.value !== '') {

    if(answers[Number(input.id)] === input.value) {
      score++;
    }

    $('#display_score').html(score);
  }
};
```

Comment: There is always `this` in function, just matter to where it's linking. In jQuery event `this` is element of event receiver, so it's totally fine to use `$(this)` inside click event function